# AppCompatDialogFragment views are null when starting AppCompatDialogFragment from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-dialogfragment

When I try to access views (by synthetics or `findViewById()` ) I am getting null returned in my AppCompatDialogFragment.

I try finding my views in the `onCreateDialog()` method. I've attached an image of this below so you can see both the call and my debugger results:

[image]

I start this AppCompatDialogFragment from my NutritionProgressFragment like so:

```
class NutritionProgressFragment : Fragment(), AddLogDialog.AddLogDialogListener {

    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        add_log.setOnClickListener { openDialog() }
    }

    private fun openDialog() {
        val dialog = AddLogDialog(this)
        dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "example dialog")
    }
...
}
```

Additionally, I have tried the following fragment managers, none of which allowed my views to be found:
childFragmentManager, parentFragmentManager, supportFragmentManager

Also oddly enough, I can sort of find my view inside the `view` object. It is under it's mChildren variable but has a different int ID value than my view. You can see in the 3rd watch variable of the photo I hardcode the internally stored `view` ID and I am able to find my EditText (although it's an AppCompatEditText instead of a normal EditText). Obviously though I can't just hardcode my view ID's based on what the system builds for me

Anyone have any idea why? I have checked many SO posts but haven't found anything that is both similar to my problem and is actually solved. I'd love to know the answer to this rather than just finding something works and forgetting this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you are referring to fragments root view instead of the view which you have inflated.

Comment: I am in line 26 because I was testing to see if that works (it doesn't unfortunately). In line 27 I call `view.findViewById(...` which also doesn't work unfortunately. I only tried `view.rootview...` out of desperation haha

Comment: What's the name of the layout with `R.id.calories_et`?

Comment: @VenomVendor The name of the layout containing `R.id.calories_e`t is `dialog_add_log.xml`

Comment: @Mackalester Then line#27 is right, line#26 is wrong

Comment: @VenomVendor yup you're correct, thanks for the confirmation on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved. Turns out that for some reason, the debugger in this situation cannot accurately interpret `view?.findviewById` correctly and just returns null every time. However, if I get my views by calling `findViewById` on the `view` object, everything will work fine. So I guess if anyone else runs into this issue, try running your code with `view.findviewById` even if the debugger says that returns null.